# Storing pointers using QListWidgetItem::setData

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I have a `QListWidget` of calendars. Each `QListWidgetItem` is logically associated with an instance of `Calendar`, which is a class that belongs to the Model side of the application.

Can I store this association in the form of a pointer using `QListWidgetItem::setData`? When I attempt to do this, I get the following error:

> error: 'QVariant::QVariant(void*)' is private

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is another constructor for void*: `QVariant::QVariant(int typeOrUserType, const void * copy)` where you should pass an unique integer to represent the pointer type.

But as stated by the documentation, you could declare your pointer type with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Calendar*)` and use `QVariant::fromValue<Calendar*>(...)` and `QVariant::value<Calendar*>()` to store and retrieve the value.

Or instead, because you are using a `QListWidget` instead of a regular model, you can just subclass `QListWidgetItem`, and add a `Calendar*` member variable with the required accessors, to avoid the overhead of using `QVariant`.

Comment: +1, wouldn't suggest the subclassing path though. (And in cases where  QVariant conversions are a performance issues, using item-based models/views will be much more so).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at this solution as well, which I think is quite elegant:
(there are minor syntax errors, but you will spot them quickly or the compiler will issue an error)

https://web.archive.org/web/20171025163314/http://blog.bigpixel.ro/2010/04/storing-pointer-in-qvariant/

Comment: The link you provide is dead. Is there any info for this?