# get correct version of item in qt

Tags: c++, qt

i have a `QListWidget` that i use it us list of filters for image , this filters is added by context menu and i reimplemented contextMenuEvent , i have 2 context menus : addfilter menu and deletefilter menu , when i add filter i just add item to the list like this :

```
MenuFiler::MenuFiler()
{

    Laplace = new QAction("Laplace" , this);
    QObject::connect(Laplace , SIGNAL(triggered()) , this , SLOT(LaplaceSlot()) );

    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), this, `SLOT(ManageControls(QListWidgetItem*)));  // to show controls for clicked item`           
    .
    . 
    .
}


void MenuFiler::LaplaceSlot()
{
    this->addItem("Laplace");
}
```

now on other function i check if there is items i get this item text and create controls for this filter and i do it like this

```
void MenuFiler::ManageControls(QListWidgetItem*item)
{
 if (item->text() == "Laplace")
    {
        if (_laplacianeffect.get() == NULL)
        {
             _laplacianeffect =  unique_ptr<Laplacianeffect> (new Laplacianeffect());
        }
        _laplacianeffect.get()->show();

    }
    .
    .
    // etc
}
```

and the controls is just some buttons and sliders linked to qframe , and i have not problem here .
my problem is when i want to create a vector to save duplicate effects for example the user add this filters to qListWidget that represent filters list:

Laplace
other effect
Laplace

so i will do something like this

```
void MenuFiler::LaplaceSlot()
{
  _laplacianeffect.push_back(new Laplacianeffect() );

    this->addItem("Laplace");
}
```

how i detect witch filter is selected

```
void MenuFiler::ManageControls(QListWidgetItem*item)
    {
     if (item->text() == "Laplace")

        {
 // what is the code that i should use to detect witch effect id is selected)

               _laplacianeffect.at(filterid).show()


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save additional user-defined data in your `QListWidgetItem`s , for example you can save all of the parameters for the effect. Use the `setData` and `data` functions for storing and retrieval. Example:

```
//Let these be the things you want to save for the filter.
int filterParameter1;
QString filterParameter2;
//etc...

//Save them in your QListWidgetItem* :
item->setData(Qt::UserRole + 0, filterParameter1);
item->setData(Qt::UserRole + 1, filterParameter2);

//Retrieve them later by having the QListWidgetItem* pointer:
filterParameter1 = item->data(Qt::UserRole + 0).toInt();
filterParameter2 = item->data(Qt::UserRole + 1).toString();
```

`Qt::UserRole` is the first place you can save your data, and you can save as many data as you want in the next places. It's up to you to make sure you save and get the correct types.

**However in your case,** an easier way may be to store a number that points to the actual effect in a struct or something, or you can even save a **pointer to your `Laplacianeffect` class which contains the parameters**.

**Edit: For storing pointers:**

Storing pointers can be a bit tricky, the standard type-system-compliant way is [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248001/storing-pointers-using-qlistwidgetitemsetdata), but as an easy alternative you can cast pointers to `uintptr_t` and save them, and when retrieving them cast them back to your pointer type.

However I suggest you either use the first method or read more on pointer-integer conversions if you want to try the second method (as misusing casts can be dangerous, due to 32- and 64-bit differences, etc).

Comment: thanks for reply , but i want to detect it on runtime on doubleclick event , any help

Comment: So when you are inserting the items into your QListWidget, use the `item->setData(...)` to save (for example) a pointer to the Laplacianeffect class which contains the parameters. When user selects the item, you can use `item->data(...)` to retrieve the pointer and get the actual parameters.