# QVariant::QVariant(void*) is private

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qobject

I'm trying to expose C++ object to QML using `setProperty();`. Here's a prototype of my code:

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass::public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyClass();

private:
    QScreen *screen;
    QPixmap myPixmap;
};
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
MyClass::MyClass (QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{

}

void MyClass::captureIt()
{
    myPixmap = screen->grabWindow(0);
    myPixmap.save("/home/john/Pictures/screen.png");
}
```

**usage in main.cpp**

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
MyClass mc;

engine.rootContext()->setProperty("myclass", &mc);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

**usage in main.qml**

```
onClicked: mc.captureIt()
```

When I try to compile something wrong happens, because there's strange error about `QVariant` (the one mentioned in the title of the question).

Do you have any minds how can I solve that?

**Update**
It's not a duplicate of what ringo has posted in the comments below. The problem is not that I can't convert my class to `QVariant`. I can. **But the problem is** that `setProperty()` doesn't let me do it. I have to put my exactly plain object there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing pointers using QListWidgetItem::setData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248001/storing-pointers-using-qlistwidgetitemsetdata)

Comment: @ringø, can you explain how is this the duplicate to what I've asked?

Comment: Please read the question up to the bottom, same problem. Then read the answer that may help you...

Comment: @ringø, I've updated my question

Comment: Is it just a copy paste error, that in your header it's called `MyClass` and in the cpp `Shooter`?

Comment: The code is completely nonsense. Can you propose a meaningful example?

Comment: It's `setContextProperty` that you should use. That's it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `QVariant::fromValue` to create a QVariant from a pointer:

```
engine.rootContext()->setProperty("myclass", QVariant::fromValue(&mc));
```